# Why do we need channels?

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, channel, consensus

#### Question 1

From the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blockchain.html) (emphasis mine),

> Hyperledger Fabric also offers the ability to create channels,
> allowing a group of participants to create a *separate* ledger of
> transactions.

This seems to mean, there is a 'master ledger' of transactions across all channels of all nodes. Apparently, [that is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46979984/919480). Even if it were true, it is not clear what is the correlation between ledgers of channels and 'master ledger'. Is there a block in the 'master ledger' to which the channel ledger(s) point to?

#### Question 2

From the [documentation on Transaction Flow (4. Client assembles endorsements into a transaction)](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html) (emphasis mine),

> The ordering service does not need to inspect the entire content of a
> transaction in order to perform its operation, it simply receives
> *transactions from all channels in the network*, orders them
> chronologically by channel, and creates blocks of transactions per
> channel.

Why does the Ordering Service work with *transactions from all channels in the network* when the channel ledgers aren't (apparently) based off of a block in the 'master ledger' (assuming, 'master ledger' even exists!)?

#### Question 3

Consider a 10 member network. There can be two scenarios w.r.t. channels.

**Scenario 1** - One channel that encompasses all 10 members.

**Scenario 2** - Three channels covering all 10 members with say, 2 + 3 + 5 format.

If we look at each channel in Scenario 2 individually, then they are same as Scenario 1 - that is, one network for each of the channels in Scenario 2. Now, given that, the channel ledgers are *separate*, why bother creating separate channels for a combination of members of the network? Why not hive them off into separate networks with one channel only?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer them one by one below.

1. Response for Question 1 : There is no master ledger. The ledger is created per channel. Kindly refer to the [Ledger definition in Hyperledger Fabric documentation.](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/ledger.html#ledger)

> The ledger is comprised of a blockchain (‘chain’) to store the immutable, sequenced record in blocks, as well as a state database to maintain current state. **There is one ledger per channel**. Each peer maintains a copy of the ledger for each channel of which they are a member.

2. Response for Question 2 : Ordering service can be common for multiple channels. In such a scenario, the same ordering service would receive transactions from multiple client applications ( which in turn may be connected to the members of different channels). There is no master ledger. Channels provide HLF with data seggregation needed for implementing privacy ( as per Hyperledger Fabric documentation, ***data isolation and confidentiality***) . Implementing a master ledger creates conflict between privacy and uniform ledger principle.
3. Response for Question 3 : When you are establishing a channel with all the 10 members, ***you have one common ledger across all the 10, and hence there is a dataset which is common across all these 10 members [current state + history]***. Now if you are creating another channel with 2 members, ***it should be just because you want to allow these 2 do something, which you DO NOT want the other 8 to know***. Otherwise, it is simply wrong. Creating the channel is about deciding what data has to be shared. It should not be about grouping them into pools.